# How to copy data from Rich Text area field to Text Area field

Tags: custom-field

I want to copy data from RichText Area field to Text Area field,When I copied in Text area field,The data is displaying with HTMl tags.  How can I convert this?

**edited to add code from comment**

```
new CaseComment(ParentId = cs.Id,CommentBody = lct.Body)
```

I'm using this in a Trigger. Here CommentBody is Text Area, Body is Rich Text area

Comment: Please add some detail here.  If you are doing this with Apex, show us the code.  If the copy is by some other means, please explain.

Comment: new CaseComment(ParentId = cs.Id,CommentBody = lct.Body),I'm using this in Trigger.here CommentBody is Text Area,Body is Rich Text area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of the HTML tags, how about replace them with empty strings using String.replaceAll?

```
String.replaceAll('\\<.*?\\>', '');
```

If this is not what you are looking for, you should as well add the example of your code, your current result and your expected result.