# Copy Rich text area field content to text area field

Tags: trigger, richtextarea

Can anyone give me the code for copy rich text area content to Text area field after save. The text area should not contain any html tags in it.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will help you, but I found the same question with answer here:
[How to copy data from Rich Text area field to Text Area field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42253/how-to-copy-data-from-rich-text-area-filed-to-text-area-filed)

Answer (score 1):

As Paul already mentioned, there already is an answer to a similar question. However, if that doesn't answer your query, you might want to have a look at the `stripHtmlTags()` method in Salesforce.

[Reference: stripHtmlTags()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex290/Content/apex_System_String_stripHtmlTags.htm)

But that will replace all the `<br/>` tags with a space. So consider replacing all your `<br/>` tags with a newline (`/n`) using the `replaceAll()` method